# Undefined jinja template variable: 'dbt_utils'

Tags: dbt, sqlfluff

How to fix the below issue in sqlfluff linting:

Undefined jinja template variable: 'dbt_utils'.
I have included
*templater = dbt*
in the .sqlfluff file.

Code being parsed:

```
config(
schema='business',
unique_key = 'calendar_id'
)
}}
WITH rpt_fact_calendar AS (
     SELECT * FROM {{ ref('stg_calendar') }}
)
SELECT
    {{ dbt_utils.generate_surrogate_key(['listing_id', 'till_date']) }}
AS calendar_id, rpt_fact_calendar.*
FROM 
    rpt_fact_calendar
```

Comment: Which dialect ? BQ or another. can you share the .sqlFluff file ? @derik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, I was running sqlfluff command from not the same directory as the .sqlfluff config file. The .sqlfluff config file was outside my dbt project directory.  I am closing the question.